# Proper version of boto for Eucalyptus cloud

Tags: python, boto, eucalyptus

I'm writing some code to interact with an HP Helion Eucalyptus 4.2 cloud server. 
At the moment I'm using boto 2.38.0, but I discovered that also exists 
the boto3 version.
Which version should I use in order to keep the code up with the times?
I mean, It seems that boto3's proposal is a ground-up rewrite more focused
on the "official" Amazon Web Services (AWS).

Comment: +1 for question. I was looking for that answer and first entered this post. Then I found the answer and replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easilly use boto3. [Here](http://blogs.mindspew-age.com/tag/boto3/) is the article clearly explaining that.
I tried it myself with Eucalyptus 4.2.1. So I defined the config and credentials file.

```
$ cat .aws/config 
[profile admin]
output = json
region = region1

$ cat .aws/credentials
[admin]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Then I used the interactive Ipython shell, so I listed my running instances.

```
In [1]: from boto3.session import Session

In [2]: session = Session(region_name='region1', profile_name="admin")

In [3]: client = session.client('ec2', endpoint_url='http://compute.region1.cloud.mydomain.net:8000/')

In [4]: for reservation in client.describe_instances()['Reservations']: 
   ...:       for instance in reservation['Instances']:
   ...:             print instance['InstanceId']
   ...:         
i-c706792f
i-af613099
i-fc0c55ee
i-4f493764
i-943d0ce3
```

I don't use *verify* argument in *session.client()*, because my testing EC2 endpoint doesn't use HTTPS but plain HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

2.38 is the right version. boto3 is something totally different and I don't have experience with it.